# PHP / SQL: Successful update a data row but got PHP Fatal Error

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a really weird issue in my code. To be short, I created a system that has a dashboard called dashboard_engineer.php. This dashboard will display only the first 30 data rows of the SQL database. This dashboard also contains 3 filtered inputs which are:

team

date from

date to

Users can use this filter to find their exact data rows. The user just fills in the input and presses the button Search, and this will redirect the user to dashboard_engineer2.php.

In this dashboard, all the filtered data rows will be displayed. Each data row contains a View and a Remove button. The remove button is used to remove the details of the data row by updating it.

My problem is, at the filtered data, when I click the remove button, the data is update at SQL database,  but it will display this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '10'. in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\tgotworker_testing\pages\dashboard\engineer\dashboard_engineer2.php:157

When I click remove button from a data row that not being filtered (dashboard_engineer.php), the data removed and no error display after that.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be appreciated. Below is my code:

dashboard_engineer.php

```
  <form method = 'post' action = 'dashboard_engineer2.php' target="_blank">
    <td width="40%">
      <select class="form-control"  name="team" id="team" required>
        <option value="">Please select...</option>
        <?php foreach ($data as $row2): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row2["team_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row2["fullname"]; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="form-control" placeholder="From" required></td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To" required></td>
    <td width="1%"></td>
    <td width="10%"><button type="submit" class="btn-primary" >Search</button><td>
  </form>
  </tr>
</table><br>
<div class="row" style='height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;'>
  <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
    <?php

    $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1 AND ot_report.status = 'yes'  ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC");
    $query -> execute();
    $results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    if(empty($results)){

      echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
      echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
            <th width = '17%'>Date</th>
            <th width = '27%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
            <th width = '32%'>Task Name</th>
            <th width = '12%'>Status</th>
            <th width = '7%'>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >
        <tr>
        <td colspan='8'>No report at this moment</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>";
    }else{

          echo "<table class = 'table-bordered' width ='100%'>";
          echo "<thead>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th width = '5%'>id</th>
                <th width = '17%'>Date</th>
                <th width = '27%'>Officer/ Asst. Engineer</th>
                <th width = '32%'>Task Name</th>
                <th width = '12%'>Status</th>
                <th colspan = '2' width = '7%'>Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody >";

            $query = $conn->query("SELECT TOP 30 * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_users.team_id <> 1 AND ot_report.status = 'yes' ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC");
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $status=$row['report_status'];
            if($status=="Pending")
            {
              $color="color:blue";
            }
            else 
            {
                $color="color:green";
            }

            $report_id = $row['report_id'];
            $datereport = $row['report_date'];
            $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
            $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);
            $fullname = $row['fullname'];
            $task_name = $row['task_name'];


            echo "<tr>";

              echo "<td>". $report_id. "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $report_date . "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $fullname . "</td>";
              echo "<td>". $task_name . "</td>";

              echo "<td align='center' style='$color'><strong>". $status . "</strong></td>";
              echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'view_task/view_task.php' target='_blank'>";
                  echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'report_id' value = '".$report_id."'>";
                  echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn-primary'>View</button>";
                echo "</form>";

              echo "</td>";
              echo "<td align='center'>";
                echo "<form method = 'post' action = 'remove.php' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove this report?')\">";
                  echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'report_id' value = '".$report_id."'>";
                  echo "<button type = 'submit' class='btn-danger'>Remove</button>";
                echo "</form>";
              echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "</tbody>";
          echo "</table><br>";  
    }
    ?>
```

dashboard_engineer2.php

```
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST["from"], $_REQUEST["to"], $_REQUEST["team"])){

  $from = $_REQUEST['from'];
  $to   = $_REQUEST['to'];
  $team = $_REQUEST['team'];

  $result = '';
  $query = "SELECT * FROM ot_report LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid WHERE ot_report.status = 'yes' AND ot_users.team_id = '".$team."' AND report_date BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."' ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC";

  $sql = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
  $sql -> execute(); //line 157

    if($sql->rowCount() > 0){

      echo'
            <div><a href="../pdf.php?from='.$from.'&to='.$to.' &team='.$team.'" target="_blank"><u>PDF View</u></a></div><br>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">   
                  <div class="row" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">    
                      <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
                      <thead>
                      <tr>
                      <th width = "10%"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAl"> All</th>
                      <th width = "3%">id</th>
                      <th width = "15%">Date</th>
                      <th width = "25%">Supervisor</th>
                      <th width = "30%">Task Name</th>
                      <th width = "10%">Status</th>
                      <th colspan = "2" width = "7%">Action</th>
                      </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>';

                        $i=0;

                        while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                          $datereport = $row['report_date'];
                          $datereport2 = strtotime($datereport);
                          $report_date = date('d M Y', $datereport2);

                          $status=$row['report_status'];

                          if($status=="Pending"){
                            $color="color:blue";
                          }
                          else {
                            $color="color:green";
                          }

                          $report_id = $row["report_id"];

                          echo'<tr>';
                            echo '<td><input type="checkbox" id="checkItem" name="check[]" value='.$row['report_id'].'></td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$report_id.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$report_date.'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row["fullname"].'</td>';
                            echo '<td>'.$row["task_name"].'</td>';
                            echo '<td align="center" style='.$color.'><strong>'.$status.'</strong></td>';
                            echo '<td align="center">';
                            echo '<form action = "view_task/view_task.php" method = "post" target="_blank">';
                            echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
                            echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-primary">View</button>';
                            echo '</form>';
                            echo '</td>';
                            // echo '<a class="btn-view btn-primary btn-sm" href="view_task/view_task.php?report_id='. $report_id .'" data-toggle="tooltip" >View</a></td>';
                            echo '<td align="center">';
                            echo "<form action = 'remove2.php' method = 'post' onClick=\"return confirm('Do you want to remove this reports?')\">";
                              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "from" value = "'.$from.'">';
                              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "to" value = "'.$to.'">';
                              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "team" value = "'.$team.'">';
                              echo '<input type = "hidden" name = "report_id" value = "'.$report_id.'">';
                              echo '<button type = "submit" class="btn-danger">Remove</button>';
                            echo '</form>';

                            echo '</td>';
                          echo '</tr>';
                          $i++;

                        }
                          echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td><p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn-danger btn-sm" name="save">DELETE</button></p></td>';
                          echo '</tr>';

                      }
                      else
                      {
                        echo '
                        <table class = "table-bordered" width = "100%">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th width = "5%">id</th>
                        <th width = "12%">Date</th>
                        <th width = "29%">Supervisor</th>
                        <th width = "23%">Task Name</th>
                        <th width = "10%">Status</th>
                        <th width = "7%">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td colspan="6">No report found</td>
                        </tr>';
                      }
                      echo '</body></table></div></div>';

                      } 

                      ?>
```

remove2.php

```
  <?php

        include('../../../config/configPDO.php');

        $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $team = $_POST['team'];

        $sql = "UPDATE ot_report SET status = 'no' WHERE report_id=:report_id";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));


        header("Location: dashboard_engineer2.php?from='".$_POST["from"]."'&to='".$_POST["to"]."' &team='".$_POST["team"]."'");

  ?>
```

Comment: Use a parametrized query instead of concatenating variables, I'll bet it will fix it.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're putting numbers in quotes. MySQL allows that, I suspect SQL-Server doesn't.

Comment: @Barmar can you help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use a parametrized query instead of concatenating variables.

```
$query = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM ot_report 
    LEFT JOIN ot_users ON ot_report.badgeid = ot_users.badgeid 
    WHERE ot_report.status = 'yes' 
        AND ot_users.team_id = :team 
        AND report_date BETWEEN :from AND :to 
    ORDER BY ot_report.report_id DESC";

$sql = $conn->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
$sql->bindParam(':team', $team, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':from', $from, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(':to', $to, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql -> execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i got this error. Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''10'' to data type int. Also at the same line

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to force them to a specific data type.

Comment: What is `10`, is it the team ID?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, problem at remove2.php. Below is the code:

```
  <?php

        include('../../../config/configPDO.php');

        $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
        $from = $_POST['from'];
        $to = $_POST['to'];
        $team = $_POST['team'];

        $sql = "UPDATE ot_report SET status = 'no' WHERE report_id=:report_id";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array(':report_id' => $report_id));

        header("Location: dashboard_engineer2.php?from=".$from."&to=".$to."&team=".$team."");

  ?>
```